# How to remove duplicate entries (which have swapped values) from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, logic

I have an array named $clashes which comprises of arrays of numbers within it.

Therefore the format of $clashes would be:

```
$clashes = [
    [
        "s1_id" => 26,
        "s2_id" => 27
    ],
    //.......
];
```

Let's say my array looks like this after filling it with data:

```
$clashes = [
    [
        "s1_id" => 26,
        "s2_id" => 27
    ],
    [
        "s1_id" => 27,
        "s2_id" => 26
    ],
    [
        "s1_id" => 26,
        "s2_id" => 27
    ],
    [
        "s1_id" => 27,
        "s2_id" => 26
    ]
];
```

As these entries are basically the same, what would be the best way to remove all the duplicate entries while leaving at least one in the array?

EDIT:

Example Output:

```
$clashes = [
    [
        "s1_id" => 26,
        "s2_id" => 27
    ]
];
```

Comment: I did not understand what you want to do. Sorting? Checking? Remove entries?

Comment: I want to remove entries that contain the same values while leaving at least one of that entry in the array.

Comment: You've given an example input, can you give us an example output?

Comment: Added the example output.

Comment: you remove not the same values in examle but the same keys

Comment: $clashes[0] why not?

Comment: Because it's an associative array.

Comment: it is array of associative arrays. 1st  level is taken by number

Comment: What is object - key, value, (key=>value)? Wtat you want to find - 1st, last, max?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather brute force method. It checks if `s1_id` or `s2_id` equals the next array's `s1_id` or `s2_id`.

```
function fixYourArray($arr){
    for ($i=0; $i<count($arr)+1; $i++){
        if ($arr[$i]["s1_id"] == $arr[$i+1]["s1_id"]){
            array_pop($arr);
        }
        if ($arr[$i]["s2_id"] == $arr[$i+1]["s2_id"]){
            array_pop($arr);
        }
        if ($arr[$i]["s1_id"] == $arr[$i+1]["s2_id"]){
            array_pop($arr);
        }
        if ($arr[$i]["s2_id"] == $arr[$i+1]["s1_id"]){
            array_pop($arr);
        }
    }
    // else just return 
    return $arr;
}

print_r($clashes);
$clashes = fixYourArray($clashes);
print('<br />');
print_r($clashes);
```

I'm sure there's a much more elegant solution.

EDIT: I removed the returns in the conditional. This should work for you now.

Comment: Thanks, this works just fine. I forgot all about the array_pop() function.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, this isn't working properly for me. This is my input data: http://i.gyazo.com/3400afb78f620c1ed76d5cb40a67a826.png and this is the data that is outputted: http://i.gyazo.com/201748bd376e21a6c07bd0b6b5fccf1f.png . As you can see, there are still entries which are basically the same still in the array after I've ran this function. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: I should mention that the data that is being inputted is not permanent and will change depending on what the user has selected.

Comment: @LiamPotter, I've edited my answer. Now it goes through the array and removes all dupes. Perhaps this will work for you. Additionally, you may need to loop through each index to all indexes to remove dupes in `$arr[0]["s2_id"] == $arr[3]["s1_id"]` for example. I must get back to work now.

Comment: Hi. I get the error: Undefined Offset '2' with the updated code.